# How do I pass custom data to Google Maps v2 InfoWindowAdapter?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to take advantage of an InfoWindowAdapter to provide custom content for the InfoView.  I'm pulling down a JSONArray from my web service and adding the Markers but I'm not seeing how to pass the detail to the call back via a Marker.

```
  @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker)
```

In the Javascript API I was able to just set arbitrary marker info. I want to be able to pass info that can be used as conditionals for the custom content, example a marker.status string.  So something other than title etc.  The view will need a number of custom fields I need to pass in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

perhaps try adding your info or object to the marker as explained here:
http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/add-informationobject-to-marker-in.html

Edit: I also made a post that continues the previous to use the InfoWindowAdapter.
Check it out [here](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/using-infowindowadapter-part-1.html)!

Comment: Yes, this seems to do the trick. Kind of surprising it's not included as an property of the Marker itself given the frequency something like this needs to be done. Appreciate the assist!